# Linux error - setterm: $TERM is not defined. /etc/cron.hourly/mcelog.cron:

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I'm in RHEL 5.9 and using mcelog-0.9pre-1.32.el5, and I get this error hourly on my mail from the /etc/cron.hourly/mcelog.cron,

Could someone help to solve this, when I type echo $TERM, it returns xterm.

thanks,

Comment: error is  : setterm: $TERM is not defined.
setterm: $TERM is not defined.
/etc/cron.hourly/mcelog.cron:

setterm: $TERM is not defined.

Comment: Is `ncurses` installed?

Comment: Try to make a way in your script to set the variable of TERM to `dumb` when it's unset. With bash running with crontab I get TERM set to dumb and with `dash` it's unset. Cab you post your crontab command? Also if there's any significant shell script that you run, try to include it as well.

Comment: black, there is ncurses-5.5-24.20060715 installed.

Comment: konsolebox: it's running on /etc/cron.hourly/mcelog.cron and content is below :
#!/bin/bash
# is this Xen?

if [ -e /proc/xen/capabilities ]; then
        # xen
        grep control_d /proc/xen/capabilities >& /dev/null 2> /dev/null
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        # domU -- do not run on xen PV guest
        exit 1;
        fi
fi

# is this CPU supported?
/usr/sbin/mcelog --supported >& /dev/null 2> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
        exit 1;
fi

# Now safe to run mcelog
/usr/sbin/mcelog --ignorenodev --filter >> /var/log/mcelog

Answer (score 0):

I expect a very simple solution: Your cron job has no terminal. So how should it use setterm for it? From your mail you should receive also the job/process/script name which runs into trouble. Have a look which one it is and fix it, if really needed.

Comment: content of the mail is :
 setterm:$TERM is not defined. 
setterm: $TERM is not defined.
/etc/cron.hourly/mcelog.cron:

setterm: $TERM is not defined.

And script /etc/cron.hourly/mcelog.cron content is already shared above.

Comment: Klaus, I already debugged the script and there is some block points in this part of the script : 
if [ -e /proc/xen/capabilities ]; then
        # xen
        grep control_d /proc/xen/capabilities >& /dev/null 2> /dev/null
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        # domU -- do not run on xen PV guest
        exit 1;
        fi
fi
 I've checked this path /proc/xen/capabilities and there is no such file there